# Sorting array of dates object not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

I have a JavaScript array below.

```
 const arr = [
     "2016-10-10 12:03:05",
     "2016-10-10 12:03:05",
     "2016-10-10 2:30:01",
     "2016-10-10 2:30:01",
     "2016-10-10 2:00:06",
     "2016-10-10 2:00:06",
     "2016-10-10 2:00:06",
     "2016-10-10 1:04:01",
     "2016-10-10 1:04:01"
 ];
```

which i want to sort in descending order or the latest date first.

I was expecting  the code below to sort my data for me

```
 console.log('the real sort is', arr.sort((a,b) => moment(b).diff(moment(a))));
```

However, the above print

```
[ 
  "2016-10-10 12:03:05", 
  "2016-10-10 12:03:05", 
  "2016-10-10 2:30:01", 
  "2016-10-10 2:30:01", 
  "2016-10-10 2:00:06", 
  "2016-10-10 2:00:06", 
  "2016-10-10 2:00:06", 
  "2016-10-10 1:04:01", 
  "2016-10-10 1:04:01"
]
```

and 
console.log('the real sort is', arr.sort((a,b) => moment(a).diff(moment(b))));

returns

```
[
 "2016-10-10 1:04:01",
 "2016-10-10 1:04:01",
 "2016-10-10 2:00:06",
 "2016-10-10 2:00:06",
 "2016-10-10 2:00:06",
 "2016-10-10 2:30:01",
 "2016-10-10 2:30:01",
 "2016-10-10 12:03:05",
 "2016-10-10 12:03:05"
]
```

It seems to me like it only reverse the indexes . Please how do i sort this kind of array accordingly ? Any help would be appreciated

**Update**

Very sorry for wasting your time. I naively forgot , mistook and expect the time to be in 12 Hr format hence was expecting the pm time to be later than am time. Not only was i wrong but it turns out that we have a an angular pipe that converts the display to the 12 hr equivalent and in local time. So my conversion should be fine, unfortunately it took me many hours to realised that . I apologized once again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date

Comment: @TimSheehan have tried that , have tried all the solutions mentioned before i asked here. I am confused also.

Comment: @zerkms i am expecting 2:00:06 being the most recent time to come first , then 1 and 12 .

Comment: Just sort them as strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this without `moment` like this:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b));
```

When you subtract 2 date objects, their `valueOf()` method will be called, which returns the timestamp corresponding to that date.

Comment: I tried `new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime()`. get thesame result.

Comment: The above code prints as I would expect: `["2016-10-10 1:04:01", "2016-10-10 1:04:01", "2016-10-10 2:00:06", "2016-10-10 2:00:06", "2016-10-10 2:00:06", "2016-10-10 2:30:01", "2016-10-10 2:30:01", "2016-10-10 12:03:05", "2016-10-10 12:03:05"]` https://jsfiddle.net/bo8bjaan/

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Sorry just realized  its in 24 hrs format. Totally misunderstood.